# Upgrading GCM to FCM server reports MismatchSenderId error

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

My current production app uses and older version of GCM.  The instructions on how to upgrade GCM to FCM did not quite fit in a couple places, but I have mostly completed the migration, and it *almost* works.

I can send messages from the developer console to the new FCM version of the app. OK, so far...

After changing the backend server endpoint to fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/ the server can continue to send messages to the old GCM versions of my app.  Just like it used to do.

But when the backend server attempts to send a message to the new FCM version of the app, the request is rejected with a MismatchSenderId error.  We are using the same sender ID that works perfectly with the GCM versions of the app.  Everyone is using the same project.  Is there something I have to do to import the old GCM project settings?  If I change the backend server to use the new FCM server keys, will it still be able to push messages to the old GCM versions of the app?

Comment: Did you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

you may need to download a current version of the `google-services.json` and authenticate with this one instead, because there most likely is/are whole other account(s) being defined by it; despite the new FCM endpoint still may process the authentication with the previous GCM credentials.

Comment: That didn't help.  Nor did actually publishing the FCM version of the app as an open alpha release.  Only thing left to try is using the FCM authentication keys and hoping that still works with the old GCM version of the app.

Comment: think one can add several keys into that JSON, just alike one can have two different JSON and/or an alternate Manifest.xml for debug builds... of course you need the actual keys to be able to sign in... while if it is released, matters the least.

Answer (score 0):

Google support eventually responded and help track this down.  It turns out that I had accidentally, and unknowingly, created a second FCM project with another sender ID.  And had registered the app with the wrong project.